# How to rename SharePoint farm including Workflow Manager

Tags: 2013

I have 3 servers in lower level environment which needs to be renamed. Three servers are SharePoint 2013 web app server, Application Server and Workflow Manager Server. I went through some documents online to set up the road map for this procedure, but got stuck when I thought about Workflow manager server and Server Certificates and SSL Certs. Can anyone has any information on this procedure.
Thank You

Comment: is workflow manager server is alsopart of the sharepoint farm or is it independent server?

Comment: Independent Server.

Answer (score 0):

for SharePoint farm, you can use the rename-spserver But if that failed then you have to rebuild the farm(due to corruption of Config DB). As per my experience with SP2010, where i renamed the whole farm(3 servers). Here what i did.

- On Server 1, run the Config wizard and remove the server from farm. rename it and then run the wizard again and join the far.
- Repeat the same for all 2 servers
- Now update the AAM and bindings and new SSL.

For Workflow manager i think the best bet is rebuild the farm. that is what [MSDN saying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193527(v=azure.10).aspx)

> Removing a server from a farm is essential when you need to rename a
>   machine or to reduce a farm to a single machine.

but you have only server then i think re built it.

Comment: Can you send me the link where msft says that.

Comment: updated with link.

Comment: In your steps after you took server out of farm did you run Rename-SPServer

Comment: No, I just remove the server from farm and re add it....for rename-spserver, i read many people having issue and with fear of rebuild of farm opt out.

Comment: Do you recommend turning off any services in farm such as distributed cache before attempting that action.

Comment: if DC is running on the server then it should be stoped and move to diff server.

Comment: I only have single host in the cache cluster, and I can take risk to losing the cached item .

Comment: yes that's true

Comment: Thank you for your insight I will follow the path of removing server from farm and reading it again, let SharePoint do its job itself.

Comment: Waqas how about Search topology, since search service application stores the machine name. Does that need to be reconfigured?

Comment: it will effect the search, check my response from technet on your new question.